# Creating polylines using javascript

Tags: javascript, polyline

i'm a beginner with jscripts, and i've been working with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, in creating an elementary map. In fact,i already have my own map, and i found a script (and did some work on it) to create/generate couple of points on the map. But i have NO IDEA how to create a line(polyline) between the points that are being generated at my map. Can somebody help me about this??
HOW COULD I INTERCONNECT THESE TWO POINTS,USING JScripts?
i think that today i googled 'polylines' more than all the people of the world together..
As I said before,i am a begginer in scripting,but what i've figured out is that the polylines are generated from arrays of the point coordinates!!?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

regards,doni

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, it depends on what you want to do really, SVG, Canvas, even using divs and rotating them will all create a line. You will need to be more specific if you want more help. *Edit* Just saw the ArcGIS, have you looked at the docs? Have you tried [This](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/polyline.htm) ?

Answer (score -1):

You can 
use the following

```
var points= [new GLatLng(x,y),new GLatLng(x1,y1)];
var polyline = new GPolyline(points, "#0000ff", 5);
map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

Comment: The question isn't about Google Maps API, it's ESRI's ArcGIS API.